# MODx CMS and SEO

Tags: cms, seo

Does anyone have any experience with MODx CMS?
How good or bad is it for a MODx-based website in regards of its SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO is *much* more a function of your templates than any CMS itself.
MODx gives you total control over the output HTML, and even has some things right in core that can be used for SEO purposes(eg. a dedicated "description" field that you might use for page-level custom meta description tags) that are often added by custom fields or plugins in other applications. That's about as good as it's going to get, unless you have more specific questions.

Comment: Okay, to the more specific question. :)
What if I want to just hand-write a site, do static HTML without the use of any CMS?
Is there anything for SEO of my site I couldn't achieve with this method that I could otherwise achieve using a CMS?

Comment: You're starting to head into an an entirely separate topic(eg. new thread) and not more specific about your MODx question, but in short: not really. A CMS will make many things *easier* or more convenient, but there's nothing they can do that you *can't* do by hand.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to know.
Thank you so much!